# Typescript: How to define an overloaded (e.g. variable return type) function type as an expression?

Tags: typescript

See the code below.

```js
function identity_fun(input: string): string;
function identity_fun(input: number): number;
function identity_fun(input: string | number): string | number {
  return input;
}

type MultiReturn = {
  (input: string): string;
  (input: number): number;
}

const identity_funexpr: MultiReturn = (input: string | number) => input; // ERROR

const ff = (i: string | number) => () => {
  identity_fun(i); // ERROR
};
const deferred_3 = ff(3);
const deferred_str = ff('str');
```

I hope you can see the issue here:

1. We can define a function using function syntax with overloads, such that `identity_fun` fully does what we want (e.g. with `const x = identity_fun(3)`, the type of x will be properly inferred as `number`).
2. We cannot create an arrow function with the same capability, as the typescript error arises:

   ```
   Type '(input: string | number) => string | number' is not assignable to type 'MultiReturn'.
     Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
       Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
   ```
3. Without the above arrow function, trying to use the overloaded regular function cannot succeed when we need to defer the input value. The second Typescript error reads:

   ```
   No overload matches this call.
     Overload 1 of 2, '(input: string): string', gave the following error.
       Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
         Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
     Overload 2 of 2, '(input: number): number', gave the following error.
       Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
   ```

Update: So the above error messages are quite straightforward, it looks like I'm able to easily handle this simple form of deferral:

```js
  function identity_fun(input: string): string;
  function identity_fun(input: number): number;
  function identity_fun(input: string | number): string | number {
    return input;
  }

  function isString(input: string | number): input is string {
    return typeof input === "string";
  }

  function ff(i: string): () => string;
  function ff(i: number): () => number;
  function ff(i: string | number) {
    return isString(i) ? () => identity_fun(i) : () => identity_fun(i);
  }

  const deferred_3 = ff(3);
  const deferred_str = ff("str");

  console.log(deferred_3(), deferred_str());
```

This shows with a bit of awkward boilerplate it's possible to let the input type travel down this way, but I am not able to figure out how to wrap it in a way that the type isn't determined until later! Will edit with more details on the attempts for that.

Comment: To fix the latter error all you need to do is add the union into the function signature. `identity_fun(input: string | number): string | number`. TS [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44392)

Comment: To fix the first error you may want to add a generic signature see [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0OaqN)

Comment: @Eldar Thank you for the tip on the generic and example. I never considered being able to use a generic in one of the overloads of a callable. Sure looks like may open more doors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what's going on but in constructing the simplified example I was able to stumble upon:

```js
  type MultiReturn = {
    (input: string): string;
    (input: number): number;
  }
  const identity_funexpr = ((input: string | number) => input) as MultiReturn;

  console.log("wow", identity_funexpr("str"), identity_funexpr(3));
```

Which... does not produce an error, does not require use of a type guard or tautological conditional expressions, and produces expected behavior. I will update if this approach won't work in my actual use case (I remain skeptical!)